# What are the rules for cross-domain AJAX requests for dynamic local content?

Tags: .net, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

If I'm using a .NET WebBrowser control, and I dynamically populate the HTML, JS content, what exactly are the rules for AJAX cross-domain requests?  I know I don't technically have a domain since it's local content, but I'm not sure how the browser handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you know what you're doing and the possibility for XSS attacks before you do this. It is possible to have cross-domain AJAX with `<script>` tags with some server-side modifications though, for example I used this:

```
var AjaxFunctId = 0
var DAjaxFuncts = {}
function CrossDomainAjax(URL, Query, Callback) {
    AjaxFunctId += 1
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.defer = true

    if (Query) Query = Query+'&'
    script.src = URL+'?'+Query+'Callback=DAjaxFuncts['+AjaxFunctId+']'
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0)
    head.appendChild(script)

    var Fn = DAjaxFuncts[AjaxFunctId] = function(Rtn) {
        Callback(Rtn)
        head.removeChild(script) // Clean up!
        delete DAjaxFuncts[Fn.id]
    }
    Fn.id = AjaxFunctId
}
```

e.g:

```
CrossDomainAjax('http://127.0.0.1/MyURL', 'myparam=myvalue&myparam2=myvalue2', MyFunction)
```

The `Callback` parameter in that function adds a `Callback` parameter to the request to the local server, so you'd need the server to output:

```
CALLBACK ID(AJAX DATA)
```

So that the function can access the data.

Answer (score 0):

*I know I don't technically have a domain since it's local content, but I'm not sure how the browser handles this.*
Then your 'domain' would be 'localhost', '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1' or whatever else you entered in the browser. Same rules apply as for any 'real' domain: no requests to other domains (with few minor exceptions).
There is nothing .NET-specific, AFAIK.